# "float" a DIV to bottom of parent DIV not working. (Using Pos: rel, Bottom 0 etc)

Tags: javascript, css, html

Trying to get a DIV to "float" to the bottom of the div its in. I've got the position set to relative on the parent div and kid, and bottom to 0 on the kid; but it still just sits at the top in the middle.

Parent DIV:

```
.detailsContainer
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Kid DIV

```
.obutton
{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;  
    width: 80%;
    height: 29px;
    background:rgba(204,204,204,0);
    position:relative;
    bottom: 0;    
    display: inline-block;
    color: #666;
}
```

Current actual setup:

```
                            <div class="detailsContainer">

                                <a href="javascript:unhide(\'BookDetails'.$row->BookID.'\');">
                                <div class="detailview"><b>Book Details<br></a></div>

                                        <div id="BookDetails'.$row->BookID.'" class="hidden">
                                            <table>
                                            <tr><td>Total Stock </td><td>'.$row->TotalStock.'</td>
                                            <td>Current Stock</td><td>'.$row->CurrentStock.'</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>Awards </td><td>'.$row->Awards.'</td>
                                            <td>Film</td><td>'.$row->Film.'</td></tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div> 

                        ';?>


                                <br><center><a href = "javascript:void(0)" 
                                onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
                                <div class= "obutton feature2">Reserve Book</div></a></center>                                
                                <div id="light2" class="white_content"></div>
                                <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>                 
                            </div>
```

Its kind of a lot to post for this, but want to make sure nothing is interfering that you guys might spot. It jumps out of php near the bottom, I'll post the entire article if you think the issue might be else where.

I tried to make a jsfiddle of it, but there is so much php and variables that by time I gutted it, it'd just be 2 normal divs, having lost its uniqueness and the issue will probably have been deleted.

Thanks -Tom

Answer (score 3):

.obutton position needs to be absolute... for bottom to work the way you're intending.

Comment: Oh, silly me thankyou. Though now it isn't centralized, hmmm.